# JPA QUERY Update data with dynamic column name

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I've a long list and according to it's substring, I'll update my table which has 10 columns. It will be like if substring is 2 update column 2 etc. So that's why I need to use dynamic column name. Is there any way to do it because :keyName for example doesn't work.

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Students s SET s.key2 = :key")
void updateKey(Integer key);
```

Comment: Please add more sample data and explanation to your question.  Can you write out all/most of the update queries you need to support here?

Comment: they're all same only column name will be changed but I don't want to keep like 10 update queries just for different column name

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general pattern which might be along the lines of what you want.  We can write an update involving all columns, except that we will use `CASE` expressions to no-op in the event that no input parameter be set for that column.  For example, for a 3 column update we can try:

```sql
update SomeEntity e
set e.field1 = case when :val1 is not null then :val1 else e.field1 end,
    e.field2 = case when :val2 is not null then :val2 else e.field2 end,
    e.field3 = case when :val3 is not null then :val3 else e.field3 end;
```

Note the behavior here is that if say `:val1` be not null, then we update `field1` with that value, otherwise we just set `field1` back to its original value (i.e. do a no-op).  For example, if you only wanted to update the second and third fields, you would bind `NULL` for `:val1`, and the two respective values you want to set for `:val2` and `:val3`.